# Можно ли ускорить данный код на Python?

Tags: python, массивы, алгоритм, сортировка

Считается, что стандартные библиотеки даже в узких тематиках быстрее, чем свои функции. Решил проверить, написал свой код для сортировки массивов чисел. Работает алгоритм наравне со встроенным, даже на очень больших массивах, но все же процентов на 30 проигрывает по времени выполнения. Может кто-то сможет подсказать варианты более быстрой реализации кода? Просто самому интересно. Спасибо

```
def my_sort_count_new_5(data):
    # будет содержать конечный вывод
    data2 = []
    # будет использована для поиска максимального числа в массиве
    # вначале равно первому элементы массива
    Nmax = data[0]
    # этот вспомогательный массив длиною до максимального числа во входящем массиве
    # в нем будем считать, сколько раз каждое из чисел входит в начальный массив 
    my_work_list = [0] * (Nmax + 1)
    # идем по массиву
    for i in data:
        # если число больше максимального, расширяем длину вспомогательного массива до нового максимума 
        # и обновляем переменную максимума
        if i > Nmax:
            my_work_list.extend([0] * (i - Nmax))
            Nmax = i
        # увеличиваем во вспомогательном массиве счеткик вхождения числа в начальный массив
        my_work_list[i] += 1

#    for i, с in enumerate(my_work_list):
#        if с == 0: continue
#        data2.extend([i] * с)
    # перебираем все числа до максимального и формируем новый массив, уже отсортированный
    for i in range(Nmax+1):
        #if my_work_list[i] == 0: continue
        # добавляем слева в массив число 'i' my_work_list[i] раз
        data2.extend([i] * my_work_list[i])
    return data2

# число чисел в массиве
I = 300000
# выводим на экран для удобства
print(I)
# формируем массив
my_list = [randint(0,100) for i in range(1,I)]

#--------замеры----------------------------------
# копируем наш массив в новую переменную для предотвращения случайного изменения при дальнейшей работе
random_list_of_nums = list(my_list)
print(f'my_sort_count_new_5: {timeit.timeit("my_sort_count_new_5(random_list_of_nums)", setup="from __main__ import my_sort_count_new_5, random_list_of_nums", number=100)}')

random_list_of_nums = list(my_list)
print(f'sorted: {timeit.timeit("sorted(random_list_of_nums)", setup="from __main__ import random_list_of_nums", number=100)}')
```

Код писал на черновик, оформление не совсем по ГОСТу. Данный алгоритм - лучший из десятков, которые я перебрал и написал. Остальные отстают от std: sorted в десятки и сотни раз. Некоторые известные даже не дождался.

Код полностью мой, не судите строго. Вариантов исполнения было очень много, но этот у меня самый быстрый, хотя чувствую, что что-то можно улучшить.

На стареньком Vaio имеем результаты (на хорошей машине на много быстрее):

1. 3000
   my_sort_count_new_5: 0.0931307
   sorted: 0.045271599999999995
2. 30000
   my_sort_count_new_5: 0.9636939999999999
   sorted: 0.6915224
3. 300000
   my_sort_count_new_5: 11.324975499999999
   sorted: 5.153224900000001
4. 3000000
   my_sort_count_new_5: 96.203714
   sorted: 53.3571046

Всем еще раз спасибо.

Comment: это клево, когда маленький диапазон значений

Comment: попробуйте модуль numpy. И вообще: https://towardsdatascience.com/surprising-sorting-tips-for-data-scientists-9c360776d7e

Comment: я numpy пробовал. Использование памяти снижает раза в 4. Но скорость даже медленнее. Спасибо

Comment: 30000
my_sort_count_new_5: 0.8892812
sorted: 0.7763636999999999 Наоборот, даже быстрее получается. Редко диапазон бывает огромен, чаще всего элементов много больше, чем значений.

Comment: Я пробовал вместо счетчика сразу appendom добавлять значения, делая список в списке, а потом просто склеить списки. Но почему-то результат неожиданный выходит, вместо одного вложенного списка Python меняет все. Хотя append и extend самые быстрые методы

Comment: Спасибо, за ссылку. Интересно

Comment: PyPy используйте и будет вам скорость)) Это конечно не совсем в тему, но кому нужно быстрее, чем на интерактивном python - подойдет.

Comment: Большие массивы можно разбить на процессы

Comment: Во-первых, родная сортировка питона написана не на питоне, а на си. Во-вторых, родная сортировка использует алгоритм timsort. В-третьих, она сортирует не только числа, но и любые типы данных, и к тому же устойчива. Так что вряд ли вы родную сортировку догоните

Comment: Я знаю. На больших массивах алгоритмизация догоняет компиляцию, будут не сильно отличаться. В моем случае речь шла узко о массиве чисел, поэтому для узких целей часто свои функции работают быстрее.